# Locating element in a pagination bar

Tags: selenium

The button in the code "AS PDF" ,As excel" are wrapped in the button Export and the export button is embedded within a pagination toolbar

I am unable to locate this element in webdriver

tried 
"//span[text()='As PDF']"

Still i see error unable to locate the element

```
<li class="leaf">
<button id="export" class="button capsule mutton up last over">
<span class="wrap">
Export
<span class="icon"/>
<span class="indicator"/>
</span>
</button>
</li>

ul id="menuList">
<li id="menuList_simpleAction.Report.exportReport" class="leaf">
<p class="wrap button">
<span class="icon"/>
<!--Item text goes here-->
As PDF
</p>
</li>
<li id="menuList_simpleAction.Report.exportReport" class="leaf">
<p class="wrap button">
<span class="icon"/>
<!--Item text goes here-->
As Excel
</p>
```

Please help

Comment: Are you using selenium IDE or java code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java code then you can use

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("As PDF"));
```

or you can get all the icons using

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='icon']"));
for(WebElement ele: list){
    if(ele.getText().equals("As PDF")){
        ele.click();
     }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: the export icon is within iframe ,i tried to switch the frame driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(0)); and then tried to locate the elemnt still i see the error unable to locate element